# Does the abstract quantum state $|\alpha\rangle$ change a coordinate transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

Consider the passive way of looking at a coordinate transformation. For example, consider rotation.

I think that a rotation of the coordinate system inflicts a change in the wavefunction $\psi_\alpha(x) \equiv \langle x|\alpha\rangle$ of a system **not** because the abstract quantum state $|\alpha\rangle$ changes but because of our description of the quantum state changes in the position representation. Am I correct?

To be clear, let me give an example. Suppose a hydrogen atom was in its ground state in the unrotated coordinate system. Then I make a rotation of coordinates. The H-atom will remain in the ground state $|000\rangle$ but the wavefunction describing it, $\psi_{100}(x)$, will be different in the rotated coordinates. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You've chosen a bad example since the ground state of the hydrogen atom is rotationally invariant, but yes I think you're on the right track. Basically they're applying the unitary transformation to the observables via
$$\Omega\to \Omega'=U^{\dagger}\Omega U$$ which means that the eigenstates are now $$|\omega'\rangle=U^{\dagger}|\omega\rangle$$ which you can easily verify. The state of our system is unchanged, however the eigenbasis components now become $$\langle\omega'|\psi\rangle=\langle\omega|U|\psi\rangle.$$

Comment: I have a doubt. In the passive rotation, when we say that we are rotating the coordinate system, do we mean that we are rotating the laboratory w.r.t the system leaving the system untouched? If not, a change of coordinates, to me, is just a mathematical change of variables and not the inverse of active rotation.

Answer (score 1):

specifically for the state $|000\rangle$ it is spherically symmetrical, so the wave function will look the same under any rotation. However, in general you are correct -- state of the system remains the same but the wave function changes due to change in coordinates.

To illustrate this, let's consider the state $|n=2, l=1, m_z=1\rangle$ of the electron in the Hydrogen atom. That is, a state with angular momentum in the $z$ direction. Now we change coordinates by rotating about the $x$-axis such that what was $z$-direction is now $y$-direction. Clearly the wave function does not describe any longer a state with angular momentum at the $z$ direction, and $\psi(\vec{x})$ looks different [for a rotation $R$ it will look like $\psi(R^{-1}\vec{x})$]. However the state itself is the same, we just call different things in different names.

A good way to describe it mathematically is that when we do coordinate change $U$, we change the states by $|\tilde\psi\rangle = U|\psi\rangle$, while simultaneously change all operators by $\tilde{A} = UAU^{-1}$. So any observable and matrix elements remain unchanged
$$ \langle \tilde{\alpha} | \tilde{A} | \tilde\beta \rangle = \langle \alpha | U^{-1} U AU^{-1}U | \beta \rangle = \langle \alpha | A | \beta\rangle$$
while if we do a physical rotation only the states change, while the observables remain the same (we still call $z$-axis the $z$-axis), which will alter the matrix elements.

Comment: if you only change coordinate ('passive' transformation), shouldn't you change both? I mean under the 'passive' rotation (just re-labelling, really) $x\to x, z\to y, y\to -z$, we have both $p_z \to p_y$ and a state $\psi(\vec{r}) = \exp(-i p_0 z) \to \psi(\vec{r}) = \exp(-i p_0 y)$. what am I missing?

Comment: If you have a vector field and you rotate both the field and the coordinate system simultaneously are you actually doing a transformation? The state has to remain the same in a passive transformation or else you've done nothing.

Comment: if I understand op's question correctly, they are really asking about "doing nothing" physically. that is, consider two physicists examining the same system, only one is using a different coordinate system than the other. the way to "translate" between the two reports of the physicists is by a changing the coordinate system, but the system is the same. that is (how I) understand the terms of the question here, as a 'passive' change of coordinates that really doesn't do anything physically, and thus all observables etc. must remain identical

Comment: @yyy I meant to say a symmetry transformation implemented in a passive way i.e., by rotating the laboratory w.r.t the system instead of rotating the system w.r.t the laboratory. Perhaps I should not have called it "coordinate transformation". Do I make sense?

Comment: @Solidification how is it different than the scenario where two physicists looking at the same setup at the lab are using different coordinates systems, relatable to each other by a rotation operation, and need to communicate with each other?

Comment: @yyy A passive symmetry transformation is not just choosing a new set of coordinates. A translation, for example, amounts to physically moving the environment of the system in relation to the system. It's not that we do nothing in the laboratory but just describe the same case with a new set of variables. That's trivial. See Shankar's definition of active and passive symmetry transformations. Also Weinberg's. This is why I feel "coordinate transformation" in the question is misleading.